# cannot import name 'RocCurveDisplay' from 'sklearn.metrics'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have updated my sklearn to 0.24, but I still cannot imprt RocCurveDisplay. Does anyone know how to deal with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you type the command you used

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the code is "from sklearn.metrics import RocCurveDisplay"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from sklearn.metrics import RocCurveDisplay
```